# How to open file from JupyterHub workspace when using %%javascript magic?

Tags: javascript, url, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I use JupyterHub in combination with JupyterLab.
I have a user "test" and a file "data.csv" in the workspace of that user.

I would like to use %%javascript magic and load that file with d3.js.

However, the url "./data.csv" does not work.

=>What is the right relative url to load files from the JupyterHub workspace?

```
%%html 
<div id = "root"/>
```

---

```
%%javascript
//define plot method
window.plot = (d3)=>{
    d3.text('./data.csv', (error, raw) => {
        alert('loaded file');
    });
}
```

---

```
%%javascript
//execute plot method
var d3Import = document.createElement('script')
d3Import.src = 'https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js';
d3Import.addEventListener('load', ()=>plot(d3));
document.body.appendChild(d3Import);
```

Related:

https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative url is "./files/data.csv".
Furthermore, I had an async issue, which I resolved by:

```
%%javascript
//define plot method
window.plot = async (d3)=>{
    var text = await d3.text('./files/data.csv');  
    console.log(text);  
}
```